# Regex that allows for A-z, 0-9, and dashing in the middle, never on the ends?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm working to create a ruby regex that meets the following conditions:

**Supported:**

- A-Z, a-z, 0-9, dashes in the middle but never starting or ending in a dash.
- At least 5, no more than 500 characters

So far I have:

```
[0-9a-z]{5,500}
```

Any suggestions on how to update to meet the criteria above?

Thanks

Comment: Do you allow there to be more than one dash between two alphanumerals--like, say `4---F`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{3,498}[0-9A-Za-z]
```

Comment: you and boltclock both have great answers. thank you. Which one is best?

Comment: Don't you have to escape the last dash in the second bracketed section?

Comment: @matthias: Not sure about Ruby regex, but in other flavors it doesn't need escaping if it's in the beginning or end of a character class.

Comment: @ColdTree: If I'm to take that typo in your comment literally, mine's obviously the best :P But in all seriousness, just pick whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 7):

```
[A-Za-z\d][-A-Za-z\d]{3,498}[A-Za-z\d]
```

If you are willing to treat `_` as a letter also, it's even simpler:

```
\w[-\w]{3,498}\w
```

Comment: you and boltclock both have great answers. thank you. Which one is best?

Comment: Mine is certainly golfier. ;-) Really though, both are just as good (though I beat BoltClock by one second, hahaha). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
/^[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z\-]{3,498}[0-9A-Za-z]$/
```

or if you want the beginning and end to be only 0-9,A-Z,a-z (instead of non dash) then:

Explanation:

The first ^ matches beginning of string.

The next [] matches a A-Z,a-z,0-9

The next [] matches 3 to 498 chars of A-Z,a-z,0-9,dash. Note that we match 3 to 498 chars because we match one char in the beginning and one in the end.

The next [^] is again a A-Z,a-z,0-9.

And lastly we match $ for the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that there are either always dashes or never dashes. It also assumes only one dash is allowed between alphanumeric characters. It's the only way I can think off hand to limit characters instead of number of instances of the string.

`(([0-9a-zA-Z]{4,499})|([0-9a-zA-Z][\d]?){2,249})[0-9a-zA-Z]`

Assuming there's no limit to the number of adjacent dashes allowed, this would work:

`[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z\d]{3,498}[0-9a-zA-Z]`