# Rails Validation that use validates a string with a regex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Message.uuid field which I want to add validations for which include:

Supported:

- A-Z, a-z, 0-9
- dashes in the middle but never starting or ending in a dash.
- At least 5, no more than 500 characters

What is the best way in rails to write a model validation for these rules?

Thanks

UPDATE:

```
  validates :uuid,
    :length => { :within => 5..500 },
    :format => { :with => /[A-Za-z\d][-A-Za-z\d]{3,498}[A-Za-z\d]/ }
```

With a valid UUID this is failing

Comment: You need to anchor your regular expression between `^` and `$`, or something like `"@%#@#$AAAAA@#%@#$"` will pass.

Comment: You should also limit the scope of your `format` validator; you currently attempting to validate length twice, and a UUID like `AAA` will cause two errors: one about the length, and one about the format. You probably only want it to cause a `length` error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd leave the length validation up to a `validates_length_of` validator, so that you get more specific error messages. This will do two things for you: Simplify the regex used with your `validates_format_of` validator, and provide a length-specific error message when the uuid is too short/long rather than showing the length error as a "format" error.

Try the following:

```
validates_length_of :uuid, :within => 5..500
validates_format_of :uuid, :with => /^[a-z0-9]+[-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9]+$/i
```

You can combine the two validations into a single `validates` with Rails 3:

```
validates :uuid,
    :length => { :within => 5..500 },
    :format => { :with => /^[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9]$/i }
```

Comment: Aren't you missing the caps here?

Comment: @Benoit I was, briefly, but remembered the `/i` on the regex which ignores case.

Comment: Just tried this but it doesn't seem to be working, it keeps redirecting. I've pasted the code I'm using above. Thoughts?

Comment: Even just using the validates_length_of with a input of 123412 is causing a redirect

Comment: @ColdTree Validators don't cause redirects. **Models** don't even cause redirects. Whatever problem your encountering, it has nothing to do with your models. Try running `rails console` and creating a `Message` with an invalid UUID, and checking which errors it has.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
validates :uuid, :format => {:with => /my regexp/}
```

As for the regexp, you've already asked for it in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261468/regex-that-allows-for-a-z-0-9-and-dashing-in-the-middle-never-on-the-ends).